# How to get event When Apps kill from Task manager in Android?

Tags: android

I want to unRegister form Sip server when some one kills app from task manager.

How to get event when app kills form task manager?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not informed when your app's process is terminated by any means, whether initiated by the user (task killer, Force Stop, etc.) or the OS on its own (e.g., low memory condition).